# Using .Net, how do I create a temp file that is readable by ALL processes?

Tags: .net, windows, security, file-io

When I use

> Path.GetTempFileName();

It creates a file in the current user’s profile that is readable by the current user; however the file can’t be read by all services on the machine.  (As services run under their own accounts.)

I need to pass the path of the newly created file to a service running on the same machine, then that services has to read its contents (don’t ask why!).

So I am just looking for a way to create a system-wide temp file without assuming the layout of the machines disks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);
```

And generate/create a file there.

Reference to the [Enumeration.SpecialFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) and the [GetFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby(v=vs.100).aspx) documentation at MSDN.

Comment: `Environment.GetFolderPath` is the proper call.